# Compile error Flash CC 1017

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

Hi all I am trying to modify some flash files provided as part of a training package supplied on a DVD.

The DVD contains the final training packages as well as all the source files. 
I have opened one of the source FLA files in Flash CC and fixed some typos in the text, then republished the SWF.

When republishing I get two errors.
    1 **Symbol 'noteBtn1'   1017: The definition of base class RolloverCursor was not found.**
    2 , **Line 1, Column 1  5000: The class 'RolloverCursor' must subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip' since it is linked to a library symbol of that type.**

I have looked at the noteBtn1 Symbol and cannot see any script attached to it ? 
 I have assumed that by simply hacking the original fla file all the correct paths and setting should be inherited from the FLA file.

If I try and run the resulting SWF file it doesn't initailise correctly leaving all the assets visible simultaneously.

The FLA file has a single scene in it with the first layer being a script layer.
There is only one frame in the scene

It has been a long time since I touched Flash so a little help would be gratefully appreciated !!

Regards

Gus

Comment: Just a thought to myself about the paths that can be specified in settings dialog box that can be accessed adjacent to the script dropdown in the publish settings. Is my issue related to not having the correct path in here

Answer (score 0):

There must some Action Script along with it in a folder which you probably didn't copy along. This happened to me as well a lot of times. Just search for the folder containing the 'as' file of RolloverCursor.as (most probably) and make sure it is in the same folder as your flash file.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, however the CD has no .as files on it anywhere and the swf files run just fine. So my issue must relate to the compile process looking for files locally maybe to incorporate into the final SWF

Comment: you are correct and I have found missing as library. However I still cannot see where the rollOver classes came from

Comment: I'm glad you found it. They would be around somewhere in codes just keep looking.  You can change global class path in Flash: Click File > Publish Settings. Click the Flash tab, if it’s not already selected, then click the Settings button next to the ActionScript Version drop-down list. Click the little plus icon above the Classpaths box, and type  ./Classes/ or ./whateverthenameyouwant/ in the textbox that appears. I hope it's the same with Flash CC. I work with CS6. I think it should be same in CC also.

Answer (score 0):

The original object in the Flash project causing the error was not used. I have removed it from the compile. This caused another error about a missing library

The missing library was a 3rd party actionscript library. This was then downloaded and installed in the same directory as the FLA file.

Import statements updated to reflect the correct package structure, the object has now compiled.

I still cannot see how to set the global class path in the Adobe CC 2014 version of Flash professional